# What is the benefit to allocate memory for a member of struct already allocated?

Tags: c, struct, allocation

My question is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12237074/how-to-allocate-memory-for-struct-itself-and-its-members).
Imagine this structure :

```
  typedef struct {
        char *chromosome,*sequence;
        int start,end;
    } localisation_t;
```

I want to allocate memory for an array (5 elements) of this structure. I will try something like :
( the syntax is certainly wrong, as you can assumed i'm not fluent in C ).

```
localisation_t *locs = (localisation_t*) calloc(5, sizeof(localisation_t));
strArray[0] = (localisation_t* ) malloc(sizeof(localisation_t));
```

I have often seen that a struct member can allocate memory too. I don't understand what for because you already allocate memory for the struct ?! But ok you don't know what it will contains.
 ([here](http://c.learncodethehardway.org/book/ex16.html) an example with *strdup* on the name variable member).
Is it a good practice to allocate memory for member of struct (mostly when it's char * type) ?

What will happen if I don't do this ? Is it a good practice ?

Comment: Your question doesn't really make much sense. And what is `strArray` anyway?

Comment: OB link: [don't cast the return of `malloc` (and family) in C](http://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/440558).

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg : even if you then use a c++ compiler ? I read somewhere it was necessary in C++ however.

Comment: @ZheFrench : You need the cast if you compile with a C++ compiler.

Comment: @ZheFrench: Yes, C++ requires you to cast the result of `malloc` (C++ does not allow implicit conversions between `void *` and other pointer types).  However, if you're writing C++, you should be using the `new` operator instead of `malloc` (and if you can, you should use a standard container type like `vector` or `map` that handles all the memory management for you).

Comment: `strArray` is unrelated to `locs` — so the reason there is that you need an array and a single variable.  If a member of a structure needs to point at memory that isn't yet allocated, you have to allocate that, too.  As a C programmer, you _must_ know (it is absolutely crucial that you know) where memory is pointed and how you should clean it up.  You can't afford not to know.

Comment: When you allocate memory for a `localisation_t`, you're only allocating memory to store the pointers (and the other structure fields), not the contents they point to.

Comment: @juanchopanza : As i said this is certainly wrong. i can remove it if you prefer , the idea was to create an array for which each index will allocated memory to store a struct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you're asking whether you also need to allocate memory for `chromosome` and `sequence` to point to.

The answer is: it depends.  You can set them to point to string literals or to other arrays, so in those cases you don't have to allocate any additional memory.  However, if each instance of `localisation_t` is supposed to have it's own *unique* instances of `chromosome` and `sequence`, then yes, you will need to allocate memory for them as well:

```
char seq[] = "CGCTATCCC";
localisation_t *locs = calloc( 5, sizeof *locs ); 
...
locs[0].sequence = "CGCTATCCC";          // set sequence to point to string literal
locs[1].sequence = seq;                  // set sequence to point to another array
locs[2].sequence = strdup( "GGCCGGTT" ); // allocate memory for a duplicate string, 
                                         // set sequence to point to it

locs[3].sequence = malloc( strlen( "GGCCGGTT" ) + 1 ); // same as above, assumes
locs[3].sequence = strcpy( "GGCCGGTT" );               // strdup isn't available

...

free( locs[3].sequence );
free( locs[2].sequence );
/**
 * Don't need to free locs[1].sequence or locs[0].sequence, since they
 * point to objects that were not allocated using malloc or calloc
 */
free( locs );
```

Comment: Yes, that's the point i'm trying to resolve. I understand your code but i'm not feeling comfortable with the concept of unique instances of chromosome and sequence.  Could you tell me more about that idea ?

Comment: @ZheFrench - basically, I'm asking if each instance of `localisation_t` is meant to have its own unique copies of `chromosome` and `sequence`, even if they contain the same values (for example, both `locs[0]` and `locs[2]` refer to sequence "ACCGT" at "ch1", but for whatever reason you don't want them to share the memory those values are stored in).

Answer (score 1):

When you do this:

```
localisation_t *locs = (localisation_t*) calloc(5, sizeof(localisation_t));
```

You create an 5 element array of `localisation_t`.  You can then safely access for example `locs[0].start`.

You can also access `locs[0].chromosome`, however this is an uninitialized pointer.  You need to allocate space for it:

```
locs[0].chromosome = strdup("my value");
```

Later, when you clean up, you'll need to call `free` the `chromosome` and `sequence` fields in each array member before calling `free` on the array itself:

```
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    free(locs[0].chromosome);
    free(locs[0].sequence);
}
free(locs);
```